# How to fix salt-minion service entering "reloading" state after executing apache.modules

Tags: apache, module, salt-stack, reloading

Facing a strange issue!

On listing apache modules on minion by executing following command from salt-master,

```
# salt 'target' apache.modules
```

on minion, salt-minion service enters "reloading" state.

```
# systemctl status salt-minion
● salt-minion.service - The Salt Minion
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/salt-minion.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: reloading (reload) since Wed 2021-09-29 00:48:29 PDT; 2 weeks 2 days ago
     Docs: man:salt-minion(1)
           file:///usr/share/doc/salt/html/contents.html
           https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/contents.html
 Main PID: 3582 (salt-minion)
   Status: "Reading configuration..."
```

Few details:

- Important to note that previously it was Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) and this issue started after upgrading to Apache/2.4.48 (IUS)
- salt-master and salt-minion both the versions are 3003.1
- It is Centos 7 VM
- service remains in "reloading" state until restarted
- minion logs does not log anything on change of service state

Comment: The service status seems to be "reloading" for the last `2 weeks`, and could be unrelated to the execution of the module. You could update the question with minion logs and details about when you triggered the `salt` command.

Comment: seshadri_c, I'm facing the issue as well whenever I execute apache.modules from salt master on any minion running on Apache/2.4.48 - One thing to notice however, is that when I run it locally on the minion (salt-run apache.modules), it doesn't put the minion in a reloading state.

Comment: The code for apache.modules is pretty basic. But `salt-run apache.modules` is definitely not the same as `salt-call apache.modules` from the minion.

Comment: @WayneWerner, do you think the minion reloading issue has something to do with response-related timeouts? Since the command that salt uses to fetch the modules (apachectl -M) is pretty simple and is working fine without salt, as you said.

Comment: You'd have to check your minion logs which should have much more information